# How to update a particular state by its id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update a particular state of id.Here `tableEditId` stores the state's id, which I want to update.

```
else if (tableEditId) {
            console.log(tableData)
            setTableData(...tableData.map((ele)=>{
                if(ele.uniqId===tableData){
                    return[...ele,{tableData:state}]
                }
            }))
```

How can I achive this?

tableData looks like this

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/uw28hScuiSxl  ,   see the screenshot.The tableData contains many objects and every objects has one uniqid and one state,So I want to update a state by its id.Id I have stored in tableEditId....  @Apostolos

Comment: so this is `tableData` i guess?

Comment: yes,right.This is tableData  @Apostolos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

When updating React state it is necessary to shallow copy all state, and nested state, that is being updated. If I'm understanding your question/issue correctly you are wanting to save the variable `state` as the new state value for the `tableData` array element matched by some `tableEditId` value.

Observations:

1. The `tableData` elements `id` value is buried/nested in the `uniqId` property, the comparison should be against `el.uniqId.id`.
2. The comparison should also use the passed `tableEditId` id value, not the `tableData` array.
3. Each element of the `tableData` array is an object, so the mapped-to values should also be objects to maintain the state invariant.
4. The `tableData.map()` needs to return a value for each element it iterates over otherwise you are implicitly returning undefined and will lose state.

## Solution

1. Use a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to correctly access the previous state's value. This avoids updating from possibly stale enclosures over the state in the current callback scope.
2. Use `Array.prototype.map` to shallow copy the `tableData` array.
3. Compare each data element's `uniqId.id` property to `tableEditId` to match the element you want to update.
4. Shallow copy the matched data element into a new object reference, otherwise return the current element.

Code:

```
setTableData(tableData => tableData.map((el) => { // shallow copy array
  if (el.uniqId.id === tableEditId) {             // compare proper id values
    return {
      ...el,                                      // shallow copy element
      state,                                      // override property
    };
  }
  return el;                                      // or return current element
}));
```

Comment: I have also done this in this way:                                                                                    
const editTable = tableData.find((ele) => ele.uniqId === tableEditId)
            const updateTable = tableData.map((ele) => ele.uniqId === editTable.uniqId ?
                (ele = { uniqId: ele.uniqId, state })
                :
                { uniqId: ele.uniqId, state: ele.state }
            )

Comment: Screenshot:  https://prnt.sc/dUjpE-p2uveZ

Answer (score 0):

If e.g. your new `state` object is called `newState`, you can do the following:

```
else if (tableEditId) {
  const index = tableData.findIndex(obj => {
    return obj.uniqId === tableEditId
  })

  setTableData(Object.assign([ ...tableData ], { [index]: { uniqId: tableEditId, state: newState } }))
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is newState here @Apostolos

Comment: https://prnt.sc/Bs7zAJjmgv01   ,Check this this is my edit function  @Apostolos

Comment: you need to update your state, so you must have somehwere a new state object. it is just an example. i dont know how your new state object is called

Comment: I have 3 states here,...1.state and setState,2.TableData and setTableData,3.tableEditId and setTableEditId.So basically the state contains the initial form data .After form submit that data stores to tableData and  tableEditId stores the id which I want to update    @Apostolos

Comment: sorry cant understand. hope somebody else can help you. please write more clear questions

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways:

```
const editTable = tableData.find((ele) => ele.uniqId === tableEditId)
            const updateTable = tableData.map((ele) => ele.uniqId === editTable.uniqId ?
                (ele = { uniqId: ele.uniqId, state })
                :
                { uniqId: ele.uniqId, state: ele.state }
            )
            setTableData(updateTable)
```

OR,

```
const editTable = tableData.find((ele) => ele.uniqId === tableEditId)
        setTableData(tableData => tableData.map((el) => {
            if (el.uniqId === editTable.uniqId) {
                return {
                    ...el,
                    state,
                };
            }
            return el;
        }));
```